# retrieving multiple data from one column using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I m new to asp.net
is there any way that i could display different data in one row where the data is pulled from same column of another table?
where the column is name hello and contains 3 types of data 
let`s say my code is like this:

```
    cmd1.CommandText = " SELECT hello FROM link where mode=@model and procedure =@procedure "
    cmd1.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
    Dim da1 As New SqlDataAdapter()
    da1.SelectCommand = cmd1
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable()
    da1.Fill(dt1)
    Dim myDataReader1 As SqlDataReader
    myDataReader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
    Dim hello As String
    If myDataReader1.HasRows Then

        Do While myDataReader1.Read()
            hello= myDataReader1("hello").ToString()

        Loop
        lblhello.Text = hello
    Else
        lblhello.Text = ""
    End If


    myDataReader1.Close()
```

my data output should be like:

> hihi,yoyo,heyhey

but i ended up getting

> heyhey

only
please help me on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the `hello` string on every iteration in the `Do while` loop. Therefore you are displaying only the last value as it is that is contained in that variable.

You need to concatenate the values on each iteration. You also need to add a `,` between each value to get the desired output.

Change:

```
hello = myDataReader1("hello").ToString()
```

to

```
hello += myDataReader1("hello").ToString() & ","
```

or ...

```
hello = hello & myDataReader1("hello").ToString() & ","
```

**EDIT:**  As the above solution will add an extra `,` at the end of the last added value to `hello`, you will need to remove it before showing the final string.

Replace

```
lblhello.Text = hello
```

by

```
lblhello.Text = hello.Text.Substring(0, hello.Text.Length - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! it works!! but the output showed extra , at the end 
which is : hihi,yoyo,heyhey,
what should i do to make it gone?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I forgot to remove the `,` added in the last iteration. See my edit.